# Add a footer on Migradoc last page

Tags: pdfsharp, migradoc

I need to add a footer on the MigraDoc. 
 The following code adds footer to all the pages.

The page has a header which needs to appear on each page.

```
 Document document = new Document();
 PdfDocumentRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(false);
 Section HeaderSection = document.AddSection();
 HeaderSection.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = false;

 MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.Image image = HeaderSection.Headers.Primary.AddImage("../images/logo.jpg");
 image.Height = new Unit(65);
 image.Width = new Unit(150);
 image.LockAspectRatio = false;
 image.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Line;
 image.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Margin;

 Paragraph ParaHead1 = HeaderSection.AddParagraph();
 Parahead1.AddFormattedText("..dfg");
 Table table = HeaderSection.Footers.Primary.AddTable();
 table.Borders.Width = 0;

 Column column = table.AddColumn();
 column.Width =Unit.FromPoint(300);
 column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
 Column column1 = table.AddColumn();
 column1.Width = Unit.FromPoint(200);
 column1.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
 Row row = table.AddRow();

 Cell cell = row.Cells[0];
 cell.AddParagraph("Regards,");
 cell = row.Cells[1];
 Paragraph para1 = cell.AddParagraph();
 para1.AddFormattedText("Support Team");
```

I need the footer table to appear only on the last page.

I don't want add to add the last paragraph as the table as the footer as that will cause the footer to appear just appear the text.

The content on the page is dynamic.

Comment: I'm not sure what the last paragraph is meant to say...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the MigraDoc footers for a footer on the last page only.

To achieve this effect, you have to add the text to the main body - or draw the footer later using PDFsharp.

You can use a `TextFrame` to have the footer at a fixed location, but you must take care that the `TextFrame` will not overlap with other main body content.

To answer the question from the comment:

- To have the "footer" directly below the content, just add it to the main body in any form you like (table, paragraph, ...)
- To have the footer at an absolute position (e.g. using a `TextFrame`): I recommend adding an empty dummy paragraph to the main body text (if needed) to make sure the footer does not overlap with the main body; the height of the dummy paragraph will be the height of the footer that overlaps with the main body area of the document

Comment: Thank you for the reply but how will I know the position of the last content in order to add the footer after that.

Comment: @user1339913 You don't have to know the position when you use MigraDoc as intended. I updated my answer.

Comment: As the content on the page is dynamic . In some cases the footer is printed on top. I need to know the height or position of the text on the last page, or how MigraDoc calculates when to break page is it characters  or row height. I can then add a dummy para and adjust its height based on the content on the last page.

Comment: @user1339913 The PDF renderer adds the page breaks when preparing the PDF file. The RTF renderer does not add page breaks at all. If the previous page is full then the "footer" will be alone on the last page - you cannot avoid that, can you? I'm afraid I still do not understand what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I used was to add a flag to PageSetup within a Section.
The flag tells the engine to replace last page header and footer with the ones specified by the LastPageHeader and LastPageFooter keywords.

This is an example of section supporting last page header and footer ( it uses a special Migradoc/xml syntax, but it's supported with the original mddl as well):

```
<Section>
      <Attributes>
          <PageSetup PageHeight="29.7cm" PageWidth="21cm" Orientation="Portrait" DifferentLastPageHeaderFooter="true"/>
      </Attributes>
      <LastPageHeader>
      ....
      </LastPageHeader>
      <LastPageFooter>
      ....
      </LastPageFooter>
  </Section>
```

A fork supporting this functionality is available here: https://github.com/emazv72/MigraDoc
Note that LastPageHeader and LastPageFooter only work with PDF, not with RTF.

Comment: Does this solution also work when rendering to RTF?